# When flexwrap is set to wrap, I want to automatically set the width of the wrap

Tags: html, css

When flexwrap is set to wrap, I want to automatically set the width of the wrap!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46vgJ.png)
By setting the flexwrap to wrap, the item is automatically pushed out, but the width of the wrapping wrap is not automatically adjusted...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xq8N4.png)
What I want is to automatically grow like above.

help me !!
https://codepen.io/laonjay/pen/YzRoZvZ

```
.flex-box {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 270px;
}
```